# non-servlet JSP

Tags: java, jsp, template-engine, juel

I realise there are EL and near EL frameworks like StringTemplate, JUEL, Velocity, etc.
However, I am not asking for list of alternatives to JSTL/EL.

I came across a package more than a year ago, someone who wrote a util that emulates the functionality of JSP for non-servlet env, i.e., JSP composition which does not need a "servlet container" to function.

I ignored it and now I think it would be helpful to me and I need help to recall what it is.

My actual motivation is similar to what StringTemplate, JUEL, Velocity would offer to help me compose SQL blocks, HTML blocks but I am thinking that JSPs are precompiled into bytecode and JSPs are more run-time efficient since run-time parsing is done no more than once.

So actually, recommendation for alternatives would be acceptable as long as the templates are precompiled into bytecode. But I still prefer the JSP emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great replacement to jsps is the [Freemarker](http://freemarker.org/) templating engine. It is excellent as a stand-alone, but also, you can see how it is integrated to [struts 2](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8.1/index.html) framework. When combined with the OGNL stack, it is a complete replacement to jsps.

Comment: Yes, that was the package I was looking for.

I am also looking at java++ which allows multiline text blocks in your java source, which java++ precompiles into proper java source code.